# Root пользователь после обновления Raspbian c Wheezy до Jessie. Как изменить?

Tags: linux, bash, администрирование, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Использую OS Raspbian на Raspberry PI. Пользователь по умолчанию `pi`. Есть таска для Supervisor'a, которая запускает скрипт автоматического обновления дистрибутива c Wheezy до Jessie. Команда запуска обновления в скрипте:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confold' --force-yes -fy dist-upgrade
```

В конце обновления есть инструкция `sudo reboot`. После перезагрузки системы, supervisor должен запустить остальные таски по установке нужных мне программ. Это нужно сделать именно после обновления и перезагрузки.

Проблема заключается в том, что после перезагрузки системы активным пользователем становится не `pi`, как должно быть, а `root`. И, как следствие, не устанавливаются мои программы, и, что еще хуже, я не могу к своему устройству подключиться через ssh.

Я пробовал делать перед ребутом `su pi`, но не помогло. Какие, в этой ситуации, могут быть варианты?

Comment: расшифруйте, пожалуйста, что такое «активный пользователь».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin подключил к Raspberry PI монитор и клавиатуру, чтобы посмотреть, стартовало ли устройство, в терминале ввел `who` и там был только `root`